# Grub2 does not detect any devices at all

Tags: grub2

I have a 1Gb HDD image (created using bximage for Bochs), onto which I wish to install Grub 2.

I understand that a Grub installation consists of 3 parts:

- The boot.img image, which occupies the first sector
- The core.img image, which occupies space following the first sector up until the start of the next track
- And the /boot/grub/ directory, in which the grub.cfg and other modules are located.

---

First I use a boot.img image that from within my own Linux /boot/grub/ directory.

Following this, I generate my core.img image using the following command:

`sudo grub-mkimage -v --format=i386-pc -o core.img -p\(hd0,msdos1\)/boot/grub ls ext2 part_msdos`

And to install them onto the final disk image, I use the following commands:

- `sudo dd if=boot.img of=/dev/loop0 bs=446 count=1` the 446 blocksize is used so as to not overwrite [The partition data that resides within the MBR](http://pete.akeo.ie/2014/05/compiling-and-installing-grub2-for.html)
- `sudo dd if=core.img of=/dev/loop0 bs=512 seek=1` and here, `seek=1` is so as to not overwrite the MBR that was just written.

---

The disk, starting from sector 2048 until the last, is formatted with an ext2 partition, and contains a boot/grub/ directory containing a grub.cfg (with a single bogus menuentry which doesn't load anything), and modules in the /boot/grub/i386-pc/ directory.

Bochs successfully boots this installation of grub all the way to the grub> prompt. As [This Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#grub.3E) points out, this behaviour indicates that grub.cfg was not found.

Upon invoking `ls`, I am faced with an interesting problem - I apparently have no devices connected at all!

To further elaborate on the nature of the problem, I observed that when booting a `grub-mkrescue` image from a slave drive, invoking `ls` displayed its own rescue drive, *and* the previously 'non-existant' primary disk drive, along with the ext2 partition. I verified that /boot/grub.cfg could indeed be accessed.

From this observation I would assume that my own core.img is missing some fundamental module or functionality. But which, and how would I amend this?

---

I also conducted this exercise on a physical machine using a USB stick, and the exact same thing happened, so I can confirm that the problem is not with Bochs.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was indeed missing a module, more specifically a disk driver, namely `biosdisk`:

From OSDev Wiki:

```
biosdisk -  This module is required for GRUB 2 to be able to boot from a LiveCD.
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the original author has found a reason for the failure in his case and shared it with the rest of community I found another issue which causes exactly the same behaviour:

`ls` invoked in grub rescue shell yields no devices.

If for any reason `*.mod` files are stripped of vital symbol information then `grub-install` silently builds `core.img` but that `core.img` cannot use any modules packed along.

Even such "harmless" stripping option as `--strip-unneeded` results in loss of two important symbols `grub_mod_init` and `grub_mod_fini`. Without these symbols grub modules are loaded but not initialized and so are unusable.

If you really want to strip grub's modules then you should add `-K grub_mod_init -K grub_mod_fini` to `strip's` command line.